# Change spritekit particle color

Tags: sprite-kit, particles

Is it possible to change the color of a particle after creating in the spritekit editor? I tried setParticleColor but it doesn't appear to do anything. Basically I want to have one particle file and a way to programmatically change the color on the fly...

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The `particleColor` property isn't working because of the color ramp settings in the Particle Editor. These are actually stored in the `particleColorSequence`, which ignores all other particle color properties.

So, to make it work, you need to override the `particleColorSequence` setter and make it nil first. Then, you need to set the `particleColorBlendFactor` to fully blend your chosen color with the particle texture (full blending is `1.0`). From then on, any explicit particle color setting should work:

```
emitter.particleColorSequence = nil;
emitter.particleColorBlendFactor = 1.0;
emitter.particleColor = [SKColor redColor];
```

Comment: The colour of the image used for the particle greatly affects the result of the particle colouring. Using a white image results in the brightest colours, using eg. a red image means only the red channel is coloured, and so on.